# Can one go from eigenvectors (and eigenvalues) to the SVD of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

If I know all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix, can I use that to directly write down the SVD of a matrix? (...of course one trouble is that for the $0$ eigenvalues of the matrix, the eigenvectors I know are not all mutually orthogonal...)

Can someone help understand if there is a shortcut to SVD from knowing the eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: In the non-Hermitian case, the answer is no. In the Hermitian case the approach is simple (you just take the eigenvalue matrix $\Lambda$ and "factor out the minus signs" with another diagonal matrix).

Comment: I am in the Hermitian case. Can you may be explain in a few equations? Like if the eigenvectors are given then how one finds the other required $3$ matrices?

Comment: What @Ian said holds not only for Hermitian matrices but for normal matrices, see second proposition in consequences  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: The eigendecomposition is $Q \Lambda Q^*$ where $Q$ is orthogonal. $\Lambda$ is already almost the same as $\Sigma$ except it might have negative entries. So you can rewrite it as $Q D \Sigma Q^*$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $d_{ii}=\text{sign}(\lambda_i)$ and $\Lambda'$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $|\lambda_i|$. Now you can roll $D$ into $Q$ to get $U=QD$, $V=Q$.

Comment: @tom Thanks; the key is just to have an orthogonal eigendecomposition.

Comment: @Ian But with $0$ eigenvalues how do I get this orthogonal $Q$ easily? The eigenvectors that one can write down for the $0$ eigenvalues are typically not orthogonal to each other..

Comment: @user6818 One can always choose an orthogonal basis for each eigenspace. If you have a non-orthogonal basis, use (e.g.) Gram-Schmidt to make it orthogonal.

Comment: I have a typo, I should have $\Sigma$ where I wrote $\Lambda'$.

Comment: In case of normal matrix you can have complex eigenvalues, than you have to pick $d_{ii} = \frac{\overline \lambda_i}{|\lambda_i|}$.